# How can I get the integral process with its quadratic variation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

If I know that the quadratic variation of a stochastic integral process is $t^3$, how can I find this process.
I tried to do it with the Itô's formula,
$[X]_{t}=\int_{0}^{t} \sigma_{s}^{2} d s$ then $\sigma^2=\frac{s^2}{3}$
but I didn't know how to continue,
Any advice or help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic variation process of the process $\int_0^t f(s)dW_s, 0 \geq t$ is $\int_0^t f^2(s)ds, 0 \geq t,$ so you need a function $f$ such that $\int_0^t f^2(s)ds=t^3.$ This is $f(s)=\sqrt{3}s.$

Comment: I already realized that I divided instead of multiplying, thanks. So my process would be $X_ {t} = \sqrt{3} tW_ {t}$?

Comment: No, your process would be $X_t = \int_0^t \sqrt{3}s dW_s, t \geq 0.$